# Jquery-contextMenu does not trigger the event on the new target element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-contextmenu

I am using the jQuery contextMenu library v2.9.2. I want to close the context menu by clicking outside the context-menu div but I also need to focus on the element where I just clicked (new target). I know jQuery contextMenu has a hidden layer and that layer has a handler "layerClick" which hides the context menu and also gets the new target element inside this handler. But the problem is jQuery trigger method does not trigger the event on a new target element unless I set the target explicitly.
Please see the attached code from the library (lines 472 & 473):

**Before my changes**:

```
 $(target).trigger(e);
 root.$layer.show();
```

**After my changes**:

If I set the new target explicitly then it triggers the event on a new target and it gets focus. For example:

```
 e.target = target;
 $(target).trigger(e);
 root.$layer.show();
```

Can someone please help me to understand this?

Comment: Apparently `e.target` is a different element, than `target` - have you checked which element the former actually pointed to?

Comment: the former e.target points to the hidden layer (id="context-menu-layer")

Comment: So that should explain it then already, right? Trying to trigger an event _on_ the element `target`, when the actual target of the event is something else, is not likely to achieve the desired result in most cases.

Comment: much appreciated. Thank you for the explanation.